# How To Save Nested Dart Models (And Lists) As JSON In The Local File System

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Here am I again with another general question:

How can I persist my (nested) model structures from Dart/Flutter in ONE JSON-File on my File System?

My models look like this:

First, my subject model:

```
import './topic.dart';

class Subject {
  String name;
  int order;
  bool isMajor;
  List<Topic> topics;

  Subject({this.name, this.order, this.isMajor, this.topics});

  factory Subject.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Subject(
          name: json['name'],
          order: json['order'],
          isMajor: json['isMajor'],
          topics: List<Topic>.from(
              json['topics'].map((topic) => Topic.fromJSON(topic))));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'order': order,
      'isMajor': isMajor,
      'topics': topics,
    };
  }
}
```

Now, the topic model:

```
import './content.dart';

class Topic {
  String name;
  int order;
  List<Content> contents;

  Topic({this.name, this.order, this.contents});

  factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Topic(
          name: json['name'],
          order: json['order'],
          contents: List<Content>.from(
              json['contents'].map((content) => Content.fromJSON(content))));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'order': order,
      'contents': contents,
    };
  }
}
```

And lastly, the content model:

```
class Content {
  String title;
  String body;
  int order;
  bool isImportant;

  Content({this.title, this.body, this.order, this.isImportant});

  factory Content.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Content(
          title: json['title'],
          body: json['body'],
          order: json['order'],
          isImportant: json['isImportant']);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'body': body,
      'order': order,
      'isImportant': isImportant,
    };
  }
}
```

What I am interested in is the way you compile all the data into a JSON-String... OK?

If anyone has a bit of time and an idea, please feel free to answer!

Thank you for all the efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `jsonEncode` function to convert `List` or `Map` to Json strings:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> json = {
    'code' : 241,
  };

  String jsonString = jsonEncode(json);
```

In the `Subject` class, `List<Topic>` is not a supported type in json so you need to convert it to json strings:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
  return {
    'name': name,
    'order': order,
    'isMajor': isMajor,
    'topics': topics
        .map((topic) => jsonEncode(topic.toJSON()))
        .toList(), // topics is now List<String>
  };
}
```